# Как отправить видео в телеграм бот

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет! Я хочу сделать телеграм бот который принимает ссылку на ютюб,и отправляет в пользователю в виде готового видео.

Я использовал для этого pytube. Но он скачивает видео на текущую директорию. А мне хотелось бы не скачивая к себе отправлять сразу пользователю.
Как можно этого реализовать ??

---

Я хочу чтобы бот принимал ссылку и отправлял пользователю в виде конечного скачанного файла. При этом не скачивая видео к себе на компьютер. Есть такие библиотеки ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вы хотите отправлять ссылку, а не файл? ну так и отправляйте ссылку вместо файла.